# ReactJs setState result not being rendered with map

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, render

I'm trying to render my `setState` results after a `setState`.
My `constructor` and `componentDidMount()` where I get my data from an API

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      students: [],
    }
  }
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3333/").then((data) => {
      this.setState({students:data.data});
      console.log(this.state.students[0]);
    });
  }
```

Here my `console.log` returns the info of my `students[0]`

```
Object { _id: "5eb44aa2bbf7137f6ed8ca3e", username: "User", email: "user@mail.com", mdp: "usermdp" }
```

I'm trying to render it (along all my other students) with that function with mapping

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    {this.state.students.map(e  => {
      return (
        <Sub name={e} />
      )}
      )}
  </div>
);
```

}

That render uses my `class Sub` which is pretty simple

```
class Sub extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.props.e}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

However only the `<h1>Hello World</h1>` is rendered.

Comment: Are you getting [object]  kind of text in html. If so change <h2>{this.props.username}</h2>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from `.map()` the `e` is the element of the array for the current iteration where you need to use one of the properties of `e`. In this way you pass down the whole object. The second problem is `e` is just a variable in the parent component, the name of the prop is `name` in `<Sub>` component based on your code `<Sub name={e} />`.

You should pass `username` property for `name` prop when using `<Sub>` component as the following:

```
{this.state.students.map(e  => {
  return (
     <Sub name={e.username} /> { /* username property */ }
  )}
)}
```

You should have property `name` in `<Sub>` component then:

```
class Sub extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.props.name}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this explains.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand how to pass property for `name` ?

Comment: @Sponge Added further explanation, I hope that clarifies.

Comment: Theprops name is the attribute you define, not its value. The name is not random. for Exemple, `<Sub name={value}>` Here, in Sub, you will have a `props.name`, not a `props.value`.

Comment: @norbitrial I understood perfectly and it worked, thank you !

Comment: @Sponge Great, happy to help!